# What happens to allocated pages that are mostly empty?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

If a process initially has a number of pages allocated to it in the heap, but a lot of the data in the pages has been deallocated, is there some sort of optimization that the OS does to consolidate the data into one page so that the other pages can be freed?

Comment: Consider reading The [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) textbook.

Answer (score 2):

In general, nothing happens, the heap will continue to have "holes" in it.

Since the (virtual) memory addresses known by a process must remain valid, the operating system cannot perform "heap compaction" on its own.  However, some runtimes like .Net do it.

If you are using C or C++, all you can hope for by default is that `malloc()` will be able to reuse previously deallocated chunks.  But if your usage pattern is "allocate a lot of small objects then deallocate half of them at random," the memory utilization will probably not decrease much from the peak.

Comment: Can the operating system even know how much of an allocated page is in use?

Comment: @TonyTannous: Not likely, in general.

Comment: The heap has no holes.  it is a continuous virtual memory range (or several, in systems that allow to allocate more data segments, with `mmap(2)` system call)  but it has no holes.

Comment: @LuisColorado heap randomization makes it un-contiguous.

Comment: @TonyTannous, have you a reference for _heap randomization_?  What is it purpose for?

Comment: @LuisColorado: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/how-do-aslr-and-dep-work

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I assume the reference you posted has nothing to do with how the dynamic memory allocator (that's a user space module) selects the chunk of memory to be returned.  This has nothing to do with what is explained here.  The space dedicated to dynamic allocation inside a process is unpredictable and dynamic,  from the outside, so no need to consider about the swapped out pages it occupies.  Anyway, should it become unpredictable dynamic (actually) it doesn't need a discontinuous heap to work.

Answer (score 1):

> If a process initially has a number of pages allocated to it in the heap

A process will not initially have pages allocates in a heap.

> is there some sort of optimization that the OS does to consolidate the data into one page so that the other pages can be freed

The operating system has no knowledge of user heaps. It allocates pages to the process. What that process does with those pages is up to it (i.e., use them for a heap, stack, code, etc.).

A process's heap manager can consolidate freed chunks of memory. When this occurs, it is normally done to fight heap fragmentation. However, I have never seen a heap manager on a paging system that unmaps pages once they are mapped by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The heap of a process never has holes on it.  The heap is part of the data segment allocated to a process, that grows dynamically upwards to the top of the stack segment, basically with the use of the `sbrk(2)` system call (that fixes a new size to the data segment) so the heap is a continuous segment (at least in terms of virtual address space) of allocated pages.  `malloc(3)` never returns the heap space (or part of it) to the system.  See `malloc(3)` for info about this.  While there are memory allocators that allow a process to have several heaps (by means of allocating new memory segments, by use of the `mmap(2)` system call) the segments allocated by a memory allocator are commonly never returned back to the system.

What happens is that the memory allocator reuses the heap space allocated with `sbrk(2)` and `mmap(2)` and manages memory for being reused, but it is never returned back to the system.

But don't fear, as this is handled in a good and profitable way by the system, anyway.

That should not affect the overall system management, except from the fact that it consumes virtual address space, and probably page contents will end in the swap device if you don't use them until the process references them again and makes the system to reload them from the swap device(s).  If your process doesn't reuse the holes it creates in the heap, the most probable destination is for the system to move them to the swap device and continue reusing it for other processes.

At this moment, I don't know if the system optimices swap allocation by not swapping out zeroed pages, as it does, for example, with text segments of executables (they never go to a swap device, because their contents are already *swapped* off in the executable file ---this was the reason you couldn't erase in ancient unices a program executable, or the reason there's not need anymore to use the sticky bit in frequently used programs---) but I think it doesn't (and the reason is that it's most improbable the unused pages will be zeroed by the application)

Be warned only in the case you have a 15Gb single process' heap use in your system and 90% of heap use is not in use most of the time.  But think better in optimising the allocation resources because a process that consumes 15Gb of heap while  most of the time 90%+ is unused, seems to be a poor design.  If you have no other chance, simply provide enough swap space to your system to afford that.